# I want use LAG function for running total in another column, but it does not work in SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

[image]

[image]

I want use the `LAG` function to determine running total in another column, but it does not work in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. If you want the running total of the precious row is the ROWS BETWEEN syntax.

Comment: I want to Use Ruuning_Total With Lag Function

Comment: use a `CTE` or derived table

Comment: Give me A Example for Better Understanding

Comment: Pictures of data is normally poorly received on Stack overflow, as we can't interact with it, however, pictures of code is never well received. If you're posting a question, don't post a picture of it. Code is text and should be posted as `text`.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the statement *"I want to Use Ruuning_Total With Lag Function"*: you can't, the error is telling you exactly that. I **assume** you want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                        SomeNumber int);
INSERT INTO SomeTable
VALUES (1),(17),(37),(24),(67),(265);

SELECT ID,
       SomeNumber,
       SUM(SomeNumber) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RunningTotal,
       SUM(SomeNumber) OVER (ORDER BY ID
                             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS RunningTotalMinus1
FROM SomeTable;

DROP TABLE SomeTable;
```

Comment: It is Very Helpfull For me , But How to Place Defualt Value is Zero In place of NULL.. In this Query                                                                                                      SUM(SomeNumber) OVER (ORDER BY ID
                             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS RunningTotalMinus1

Comment: Use [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).